# Confusion regarding conductors and their behavior

Tags: electromagnetism

Consider two thin plates and one thick plate(all conducting). A and C are the thin plates, B is the thick one. Now B is inserted between the parallel plates A and C. A is given a charge 2q and C is given -q. What charges will be induced on eavh side of B? Although this may seem simple, one can obviously realise that it wont be -2q and q on the sides of B, as the plate must be neutral. I tried hard, but found no explanation leading to the answer. Does this have to be determined experimentally only?
Note: the plates have infinite dimensions.

Comment: Also note that this is purely a confusion, and not a homework question.

Comment: Why would the thickness of the plates matter? Tell your teacher to stop using infinite size systems. They don't exist in nature. The proper way to specify this is to say that the distance between the plates is negligible compared to their dimensions.

Comment: I agree, even if thats the case, is there a simplr answer to this?

Comment: Where were the charges located on A and C before B was inserted?

Comment: B was inserted first. Then A and C were given 2q and -q respectively.

Comment: The net charge of the system will be on the outside.

Comment: Work trough it by establishing what must happen if you add charge to one of the outer plates, first.

Comment: ... maybe this helps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wo83ZpOY5xw

Comment: @Previous i can agree to your commen if the potential of plate B was at zero. Then by uniqueness theorem, nrt vharge wouldve been on the outside. Is the middle plate at zero potential here?

Comment: The induced charge will be distributed such that the internal field  in your thick plate is zero. I asked a similar question recently http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/265270/regarding-the-zero-internal-electric-field-in-a-conductor-electrostatic-case still waiting for an answer

Comment: @ R.Rankin thats obvious, only such distribution is hard to find, satisfying all the conditions.

Comment: @Lelouch The way they did it in the olden days: total charge= q, put half on each outer side (of A and C), balance out the other sides: 0.5q A 1.5q .. -1.5q B 1.5q .. -1.5q C 0.5q

Comment: @Lelouch : if you formulate your problem as two charged plates A and C (we don't quite care what they made of but the idea is to impose their surface charge) and a thick conducting plate B related to the ground at fixed potential zero; then plate B will get a net charge from the ground and have surface charges balancing respectively A and C...unless I am missing something

Comment: I have voted to leave this question open.  The comments demonstrate that it is on-topic and that a definite answer can be given.  I think the only criticism which can be made is that the OP has not shown sufficient effort to tackle the problem himself.

Comment: @sammygerbil .... i did have a reason. There is hardly any way i can find to proceed. Anything i know seems to fire back halfway through.

Comment: You could state the process of reasoning which ended in you concluding that it "back-fired".  ie What principles have you applied?  What assumptions have you made? Where exactly is your reasoning leading to an impossible result? I appreciate you've realised that you cannot have charges of -2q and +q on opposite faces of a neutral conductor.  But is that all?  It seems not because you say "anything I try" backfires.

Comment: Related : Why isn't the electrical field between two parallel conducting plates quadrupled?: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/101816

Comment: I also thought that all the charges will move near the edges  of the plates and the fringe effects will have to be taken into account.

Comment: Fringe effects?  Aren't the plates infinite in extent?  There are no "edges".

Comment: Theoretically yes-....can't the charges move out to infinity? And leave no charges  inside? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state that the plates are infinite in extent.

One problem this creates is that a finite charge placed on them creates infinitessimal surface charge density and therefore no (or infinitessimal) electric field.  So instead I shall interpret your question to mean that the plates are finite in extent but the distances between them are much smaller than their lateral dimensions.  Then fringing effects can be neglected. Alternatively you can consider plates which extend to infinity but the charges given result in finite surface charge densities.

---

Possibly the easiest way to arrive at the answer is by using the Superposition Principle, which states that the interaction between two charges is not affected by the presence of other charges.

So we can imagine that the 3 conductors are initially uncharged, in the order A, B, C from left to right, and then consider the effect of placing charges on each in turn.

The charge of $+2q$ placed on A distributes itself equally over both faces, $+q$ on each. The charge of $+q$ on the RH face of A induces charges of $-q$ and $+q$ on the LH and RH faces of B [1].  The latter induces charges of $-q$ and $+q$ on the LH and RH faces of C.

B is not charged so we do no need to consider this.

The charge of $-q$ placed on C distributes itself equally over both faces, $-\frac12q$ on each. The charge of $-\frac12q$ on the LH face of C induces charges of $+\frac12q$ and $-\frac12q$ on the RH and LH faces of B.  The latter induces charges of $+\frac12q$ and $-\frac12q$ on the RH and LH faces of A.

Finally we add the charges on each face :

charge from A :  $.+q.| A | .+q ..... .-q. | B | .+q ..... .-q. | C | .+q$
charge from C :  $-\frac12q | A | +\frac12q ..... -\frac12q | B | +\frac12q ..... -\frac12q | C | -\frac12q$

total charges :  $+\frac12q | A | +\frac32q ..... -\frac32q | B | +\frac32q ..... -\frac32q | C | +\frac12q$

---

Note [1] :  *I am not entirely happy with this argument.  If the presence of charge on A causes a polarisation of charge on B, doesn't the polarisation of B cause a re-distribution of charge on A, as it has done with C?  Of course we can make B infinitessimally thin, as we can with A and C as gatsu suggests in the comment below. But if we do so, the concepts of induced polarisation and the charge on each face become meaningless.*

*Those answering the linked question  [Why isn't the electrical field between two parallel conducting plates quadrupled?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/101816)  also had some difficulty with the situation.*

---

For reference, the solution suggested by Previous is demonstrated in the following videos.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wo83ZpOY5xw
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTYQk110Xhg

Comment: Yes. The key to Lelouch confusion, I think, is that the problem is underdetermined if one considers the plates A and C to be infinitesimally thin. It is possible to keep them infinitely thin but then you need to specify what is the induced charge on one side of B in the boundary conditions (this imposed charge captures in essence the response of the plates A and C to the polarisation of B).